# Confused about example of creating a formal grammar

Tags: grammar

I'm reading Dick Grune's [Parsing Techniques - A Practical Guide](http://www.dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_1st_Edition/) and I'm stuck on an example of what a formal grammar is (starting page 22).  He starts with this:

```
0. Name may be replaced by “tom”
   Name may be replaced by “dick”
   Name may be replaced by “harry”
1. Sentence may be replaced by Name
2. Sentence may be replaced by Sentence, Name
3. “, Name” at the end of a Sentence must be replaced by “and Name”
   before Name is replaced by any of its replacements
4. a sentence is finished only when it no longer contains non-terminals
5. we start our replacement procedure with Sentence
```

Then he re-writes this more formally as follows:

```
0. Name -> tom
   Name -> dick
   Name -> harry
1. Sentence -> Name
   Sentence -> List End
2. List -> Name
   List -> List , Name
3. , Name End -> and Name
4. the start symbol is Sentence
```

The re-write above (figure 2.2 in the book) introduces "List".  I assume List is a non-terminal, but I can't figure out where it comes from or what it means.

Also, unless I mis-read the text, figure 2.2 is supposed to be the same as the first figure, but they don't exactly match.  For example, where is rule #2 from the first figure ("Sentence may be replaced by Sentence, Name") in fig. 2.2?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that [questions about formal languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309055/are-formal-languages-on-topic]) are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't copy the table properly.
2 must be:

List -> Name

List -> List , Name

List can either be a single name or a list, a comma and a name.

e.g. "dick , tom and harry" is a valid sentence because we construct it the following way:

Sentence                (Replace Sentence)

List End                (List will be replaced with "List , Name")

List , Name End         (Replace List with "List , Name" again)

List , Name , Name End  (Now replace List with Name)

Name , Name , Name End  (Replace ", Name End" with "and Name")

Name , Name and Name    (Replace the Names)

dick , tom and harry

I hope this will answer your second question as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo.  But that doesn't quite get me there.  Is "List" just a made up symbol like "end" and "name"?

Comment: Yes it is. And it is non terminal. The only terminals are "tom", "dick" and "harry".

And you can find rule #2 in the combination of rules 1.2 and 2.2 because "Sentence" may be replaced by "List End" and "List" may be replaced by "List , Name". So you get "List , Name End" which corresponds to sentence, name in the upper text.